# MySQL: JOIN vs nested SELECT, suggestion required

Tags: mysql, join, select

I've read similar topics, but found nothing related.

Environment:

OCS-NG MySQL database on the OCS-NG server. Full access. The main table is HARDWARE.

```
ID integer
NAME string -- hostname of the computer
(other fields, out of Q's context)
```

Related tables. Both have PK by the ID field, and additional key by HARDWARE_ID field

DRIVES TABLE (really - partitions on storage devices, one record per partition)

```
ID
HARDWARE_ID -- link to HARDWARE.ID
TYPE -- Hard drive, CD-Rom drive, removable drive (for windows) or mount point for partition (for linux)
(other fields, out of Q's context)
```

STORAGES TABLE (list of the storage devices found on particular computer, one record per storage device)

```
ID
HARDWARE_ID -- link to HARDWARE.ID
TYPE -- Fixed hard disk media, DVD-(ROM|writter), ROM (IDK what's it),Removable media (for windows), cd, disk, loop (for linux), NULL (for floppies and card-readers)
DISKSIZE -- in Gbs, zero if no media in drive ie. for opticals or card-readers
(other fields, out of Q's context)
```

It is clear that the HARDWARE related to DRIVES and STORAGES in 1:MANY manner. Other field are omitted because they in no way related to question. Users of the OCS-NG Inventory may reproduce my attempts on their systems, others may recreate the training tables with minimal usable data sets with ease, if they would to reproduce the situation.

I tried to get the report of how many HDDs have the computers in my organization (number of devices per PC) and how many partitions defined in each PC. Expected results:

```
name, id, drives, parts
'DOD-3-SRL01', '560', '2', '7'
'DOD-3-WS000', '1', '1', '2'
'DOD-3-WS0000', '31', '1', '2'
'DOD-3-WS001', '660', '1', '2'
'DOD-3-WS002', '268', '2', '2'
```

where DRIVES column is the number of HDDs, and PARTS column is total number of partitions on these HDDs. The table above shows, for example, that the SRL01 have 2 HDDs with 7 partitions in total, and WS002 have two HDDs with two partitions, probably one per HDD. The Windows' hidden partitions (like "reserved by system" or not recognizable by Windows like ext4) not stored in the database.

I tried different approaches with the JOINs, but got no usable results. As a final resort I used the nested SELECTs w/o any JOINs. It works, but I feel myself confused: did I do something wrong or the JOIN just unsuitable for this task?

The code with the nested SELECTs.

```
SELECT 
    UPPER(hw.name),
    hw.id,
    (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM storages
        WHERE type LIKE '%disk%'
        AND HARDWARE_ID = hw.ID) drives,
    (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM drives
        WHERE (type LIKE '%hard%' OR type LIKE '/%') -- "/%" is for Linux' mount points like "/home"
        AND HARDWARE_ID = hw.ID) parts
FROM hardware hw
ORDER BY hw.name
```

This code works fine. But I'm pretty sure it is not efficient. And, as I already said, I would like to use JOINs instead SELECTs at least because these tables have relations at the database level. Any suggestions please?

Thank you for the time you spent for this long reading.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.